# My armature is not visible but my character still moves

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigging, 3d-view, armature, bones

I went back to an old project to append a character I had made, but for some reason the bones aren't visible. I tried pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> but it wasn't hidden. The character still follows the animation from the armature. The writing for the armature is grey in the outliner.

I am using blender 3.0 with cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you duplicate an object without selecting it's parent or opposite and moving the new duplicate to a new collection.

Delete your armature with it's object and go to the original one and <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the armature, then *select Hierarchy* and then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and place it where you want to. Then press <kbd>M</kbd> to move it to the collection that last one was.

Comment: I don't think I duplicated it, when i delete the armature with it's object it's just gone and there's no original one left. Here's the blend file, maybe it can help.                             [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=v2RAom8x" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/v2RAom8x/)

Answer (score 0):

Your armature is not disabled. Actually it's disabled from rendering in view port.
Click on filters icon in the *outliner* tab:

[image: filters picture]

Then press *Disable in viewport* button :

[image: Disable in view port button]

Then select your object in *outliner* and click on screen icon :

[image: screen icon]